# Why i can't watch the expression a[1][1] after declare it by a[n][n] in c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n=5;
    int a[n][n];
    a[1][1]=5;
    return 0;
}
```

I got this error when trying to watch the expression a[1][1] in eclipse on line 6:

> Failed to execute MI command:
>   -data-evaluate-expression a[1][1] Error message from debugger back end:
>   Cannot perform pointer math on
>   incomplete types, try casting to a
>   known type, or void *.

i guess it's returned from gdb? however, i don't know why i can't watch that value? Isn't "a" is a normal multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some odd reasons this isn't valid C++ unless you make it

```
const int n = 5;
```

Otherwise the array size is formally unknown until runtime.

Comment: "some odd reason" is that variable length arrays are not part of C++.

Comment: @avakar - The odd part is that everyone can see that n is always 5. It says so on the line above the matrix, and n is never changed (in this code).

Comment: actually the program run well @@ i just can't debug a[1][1], but i can still set its value/ get its value using program code ... Does that mean a has been created during run-time?

Comment: @Chan - the g++ compiler has an extension that accepts the code for C++. It is valid in C99, so the compiler knowns how to handle it. Perhaps the debugger does not?

Comment: @Bo Persson : `The odd part is that everyone can see that n is always 5` : There is a difference between a correct C++ syntax ("you can only initialize an array size with a `const` value") with a compiler optimization done *after* the syntax verification ("Oh, it's 5 and currently, no one changed it, so I guess it should be Ok to inline the value").

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't suppose variable length array (VLA).  So your code is not standard conformant code.

It will not compile if you compile it with `g++ -pedantic`. The array size must be constant expression. But in your code, its not.

So write:

```
 const int n=5; //now this becomes constant!
 int a[n][n]; //the size should be constant expression.
```

Lets try the above code, as its completely Standard conformant code now.

Answer (score 0):

why not better do it a dynamic 2d array? In that case you do not have to make the n constant, and you can determine the size dynamically.

```
int **arr, n;

arr = new int * [n]; // allocate the 1st dimension. each location will hole one array
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  arr[i] = new int [n]; // allocate the 2nd dimension of one single n element array
                        // and assign it to the above allocated locations.
}
```

Now you can access the aray as `arr[i][j]`

To free to the reverse

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  delete [] arr[i]; // first delete all the 2nd dimenstion (arr[i])
}
delete [] arr; // then delete the location arays which held the address of the above (arr)
```